# how to add single element to array object

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can I append a single value to an array that is stored as an object of the class Citations?

```
class Citations
    attr_accessor :paper,:arr

    def dothing()
        return paper.to_s.length
    end 
end

cit = Citations.new


#(1...5).each{ |x| cit.arr << x } # fails
cit.arr = [1,2,3,4] # works if I add the entire array as one unit
puts cit.arr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, this line: `(1...5).each { |x| cit.arr << x }` fails with error message:

```
undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

If you read the error message carefully, you will see that it indicates: `cit.arr` is `nil` because you did not initialize it and so when you call this: `cit.arr << x`, it's actually trying to call `<<` method on the `nil` and fails because `<<` method is not implemented on `NilClass` objects.

So, you need to initialize `arr` before calling `cit.arr << x` so that `cit.arr` is not `nil`.

You can do that in the `initialize` method of your class like this:

```
class Citations
    attr_accessor :paper,:arr

    def initialize
        @arr = []
    end
# rest of the codes
end
```

This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

It fails because the array `arr` is not initialized. Change your class to this:

```
class Citations
    attr_accessor :paper,:arr
    def initialize
        @arr = []
    end
    def dothing()
        return paper.to_s.length
    end 
end
```

Naturally, your second attempt works fine because by using

```
cit.arr = [1,2,3,4]
```

You are in fact initializing it.

I can see a similar issue happening to `paper` (whatever it is).